# Printing values of float and int for a simple calculation (values not adding up)

Tags: c, floating-point

Having trouble with float / int calculations for a program designed to convert a dollar value input into its possible constituent parts. For example, if you enter $ 1234.56, the program will output "1 $1000 bill, 2 $100 bills, 1 $20 bill, 1 $10 bill, 4 $4 dollar bills, 2 Quarters, 1 Nickel, and 1 cent."

The biggest issue comes up with calculating pennies. If the user inputs $ .03, the output will vary (at times, I get 3 cents; other times, I get 2 cents). I think I have solved the issue for now, but I would like to understand why I solved it and more importantly I'd like to address the underlying issue: somewhere along the calculation stream, the compiler appears to "shave off" value (e.g. .01 becomes .009999). Is it because I'm performing a recursive calculation on the same variable, namely "amount"? Is there a cleaner way to do what I am trying to do here? (I'm limited to switch / if selection statements, no use of functions, and no use of arrays.)

Link to full code [here](https://paste.ofcode.org/Mre8SaKHkgz8GHAQCTLbNi).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

float amount, bill_quarter_f, bill_dime_f, bill_nickel_f, bill_penny_f;
int bill_quarter, bill_dime, bill_nickel, bill_penny;

printf("Ex 5.15: Translating Decimal Dollar into Coins\n");
printf("==============================================\n\n");

printf("Enter your amount (e.g .98): $ ");
scanf("%f", &amount);

/************************************/
/* Calculation for greater than MAX */
/************************************/

if (amount >= 1)
    printf("\nYou have too much money!\n\n");

/************************************/
/*       Calculation for Coins      */
/************************************/

else if(amount < 1 && amount > 0){
    bill_quarter = amount / .25;
    bill_quarter_f = amount / .25;
    amount = ((bill_quarter_f - bill_quarter) * .25);


    (bill_quarter >= 1 && bill_quarter < 4) ? (printf("You have %d quarters\n", bill_quarter)) : (printf(""));

    bill_dime = amount / .10;
    bill_dime_f = amount / .10;
    amount = (bill_dime_f - bill_dime) * .10;


    (bill_dime >= 1 && bill_dime <= 2) ? (printf("You have %d dimes\n", bill_dime)) : (printf(""));

    bill_nickel = amount / .05;
    bill_nickel_f = amount / .05;
    amount = (bill_nickel_f - bill_nickel) * .05;


    (bill_nickel >= 1 && bill_nickel < 2) ? (printf("You have %d nickel\n", bill_nickel)) : (printf(""));

    bill_penny = amount / .01;
    bill_penny_f = amount / .01;
    amount = (bill_penny_f - bill_penny) * .01;

    (bill_penny_f > 0 && bill_penny_f < 5) ? (printf("You have %.0f pennies\n", bill_penny_f)) : (printf(""));
}

else if (amount == 0)
    printf("You have no money!\n");
else
    printf("You are in debt!\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use fixed-point arithmetic for monetary types; floating-point is completely unsuitable (binary floating-point especially so).

Comment: @TobySpeight  Fixed-point arithmetic for monetary types has it weaknesses too. " floating-point is completely unsuitable" --> Decimal FP is great - aside from its lack of support.  Its a trade-off, regardless of the route taken.

Comment: @chux, I've never tried decimal floating-point for money; I'd rather use those exponent digits for actual value, rather than for scaling (and so varying the (absolute) precision at unexpected times).  But if you have the experience, I'd love to hear how it works for you, perhaps in an answer somewhere?

Comment: @OP  "Is it because I'm performing a ... [this] or [that]?"  --> the point is that when using FP for money, code needs a definition of how to handle  results  only _near_ a multiple of the smallest unit 0.01.

Comment: @chux Thanks for your answer. What's incomplete about my post? I am a beginner,  and not that I want to fall back on that, but I am puzzled by why my post is incomplete. Lastly, the only variable types the author (KN King) has introduced so far are float and int; so, I am wondering whether this exercise was meant to force the reader to avoid using float.

Comment: @user8287021 "What's incomplete about my post?" --> The posted code does not compile.  To improve, post a piece of code that is compilable.  [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/29485) is useful.

Comment: @chux Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using binary floating-point for financial code has various pitfalls.  OP's code exhibits some of those.  Without addressing other other ways to represent money (each with their strengths and weaknesses), this answer presents ways to improve `double` usage with money as it applies to OP's code.

1. Inexact representation of money

Recall a [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) `double` can typically *exactly* represent about 2<sup>64</sup> different numbers.  `0.10` is *not* one of them.  So the following quotient will often result in a non-whole-number.

```
float amount;
...
amount / .10;
```

Assigning the quotient to an `int` results in a truncated value.  Had the `quotient` been 1.9999..., `bill_dime` would take the value of 1.

```
int bill_dime;
...
bill_dime = amount / .10;
```

2. No control over input that is not an exact multiple of 0.01.

What to do with user input like `"0.125"` --> `amount = 0.125`?

`0.125` can be exactly represented as `double`, so there is no rounding issue on input.  Yet code does not address how to round such a value or what to do with fraction of 0.01.

2. No control over inputing rounded values.

What to do with user input like `"0.10"` --> that value can not be exactly represented?  So a nearby  `amount = 0.10f` results.

`value` takes on a `float` value  `0.01f` that is *near* 0.01 and may differ from a `double`  `0.01`. This difference may result in an unexpected result from `amount / .10;`.  Mixing `double` and `float` contributed to this problem.

---

For financial code employing FP, do not use `float` - far too many issues.

For OP's learner usage of FP and financial code, recommend to convert the FP input to integers for change computation.  As the conversion to `long` below certainly does not overflow, that concern of OF can be set aside.

```
printf("Enter your amount (e.g .98): $ ");
double amount;
if (scanf("%lf", &amount) != 1) Handle_NonNumericInput();

if (amount >= 1.0 || amount < 0.0)
  printf("\nYou have too much/too little money!\n\n");
```

Now move to integers

```
 else {
   // round ... to the nearest integer value, rounding halfway cases away from zero,
   long cents = lround(amount * 100.0);
   // 0 <= cents <= 100
   // Need to decide how to handle cents == 0 or cents == 100 here.

   bill_quarter = cents / 25;
   cents %= 25;

   if (bill_quarter) {
     printf("You have %d quarters\n", bill_quarter);
   }

  bill_dime = cents / 10;
  cents %= cents % 10;

   if (bill_dime) {
     printf("You have %d dimes\n", bill_dime);
   }
```

---

Minor

```
// "You have %d nickel"
"You have %d nickels"
```